# android googlemap export to share

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, kml, kmz

I have an app with a google map fragment. I have added some markers and polygons, all within a 1km square.

Ultimately I would like to export the map to a pdf using code. Im guessing the first step would be to create a kml file with my objects.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take bitmap of the map by calling `map.snapshot(...)`
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback)

After this you can make with bitmap what you want, export to pdf with some library and share, for example.

Comment: thanks but i need to send to another user and it looks like a might breach that clause